# asp.net - Unable to set Identity in owin after successful custom authentication

Tags: asp.net, wcf, asp.net-identity, forms-authentication, session-cookies

I am using wcf service for authentication and communication with database. After success authentication, in client web application, I am trying to set Identity for login user using following code.

```
    private async Task SignIn(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(
            user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        GetAuthenticationManager().SignIn(identity);
    }

    private IAuthenticationManager GetAuthenticationManager()
    {
        var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
        return ctx.Authentication;
    }
```

Even after execution of above code i.e. setting identity  Request.IsAuthenticated still return false.

I have found above code is working fine in an online [sample](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-1) which is using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core version 1.0.0 library.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: When do you expect the user to be logged in (after `GetAuthenticationManager().SignIn(identity);` or later?

Comment: After signIn Call, at this point asp identity should set authentication cookie and change status to authenticated

Comment: nope... The authentication is set at the request stage, therefore you will see the user as being authenticated only at the next request.

Comment: Users never get authenticated even on next request